# how to my two mesh data(.stl) registration with open3d in python

Tags: registration, open3d

use MacO sonoma14.1.2
use python version 3.9.18
my library is newest version

http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/pipelines/global_registration.html
I succeeded in matching the two demo data by referring to the code in the link above.

But when I load my mesh data, the registration doesn't work.

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
from vtk  import *
import copy




def draw_registration_result(source, target, transformation):
    source_temp = copy.deepcopy(source)
    target_temp = copy.deepcopy(target)
    source_temp.paint_uniform_color([1, 0.706, 0])
    target_temp.paint_uniform_color([0, 0.651, 0.929])
    source_temp.transform(transformation)
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_temp, target_temp],
                                      zoom=0.4559,
                                      front=[0.6452, -0.3036, -0.7011],
                                      lookat=[1.9892, 2.0208, 1.8945],
                                      up=[-0.2779, -0.9482, 0.1556])



def preprocess_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size):
    print(":: Downsample with a voxel size %.3f." % voxel_size)
    pcd_down = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size)

    radius_normal = voxel_size * 2
    print(":: Estimate normal with search radius %.3f." % radius_normal)
    pcd_down.estimate_normals(
        o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=radius_normal, max_nn=30))

    radius_feature = voxel_size * 5
    print(":: Compute FPFH feature with search radius %.3f." % radius_feature)
    pcd_fpfh = o3d.pipelines.registration.compute_fpfh_feature(
        pcd_down,
        o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=radius_feature, max_nn=100))
    return pcd_down, pcd_fpfh





def prepare_dataset(voxel_size):
    print(":: Load two point clouds and disturb initial pose.")

    # demo_icp_pcds = o3d.data.DemoICPPointClouds()
    # source = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(demo_icp_pcds.paths[0])
    # target = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(demo_icp_pcds.paths[1])


    source_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh('/Users/kisoup/ready/BME major/3-2/Advanced  Medical image processing and Lab/Project/code/data/etc/lumberN_t_1.stl')
    target_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh('/Users/kisoup/ready/BME major/3-2/Advanced  Medical image processing and Lab/Project/code/data/etc/lumberN_t_2.stl')
    source = source_mesh.sample_points_uniformly(10000)
    target = target_mesh.sample_points_uniformly(10000)

    
    trans_init = np.asarray([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                             [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
    
    draw_registration_result(source, target, np.identity(4))
    
    source_down, source_fpfh = preprocess_point_cloud(source, voxel_size)
    target_down, target_fpfh = preprocess_point_cloud(target, voxel_size)
    return source, target, source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh





def execute_global_registration(source_down, target_down, source_fpfh,
                                target_fpfh, voxel_size):
    distance_threshold = voxel_size * 1.5
    print(":: RANSAC registration on downsampled point clouds.")
    print("   Since the downsampling voxel size is %.3f," % voxel_size)
    print("   we use a liberal distance threshold %.3f." % distance_threshold)
    result = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_ransac_based_on_feature_matching(
        source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh, True,
        distance_threshold,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint(False),
        3, [
            o3d.pipelines.registration.CorrespondenceCheckerBasedOnEdgeLength(
                0.9),
            o3d.pipelines.registration.CorrespondenceCheckerBasedOnDistance(
                distance_threshold)
        ], o3d.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria(100000, 0.999))
    return result



def refine_registration(source, target, source_fpfh, target_fpfh, voxel_size):
    distance_threshold = voxel_size * 0.4
    print(":: Point-to-plane ICP registration is applied on original point")
    print("   clouds to refine the alignment. This time we use a strict")
    print("   distance threshold %.3f." % distance_threshold)
    result = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
        source, target, distance_threshold, result_ransac.transformation,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPlane())
    return result




voxel_size = 0.05  # means 5cm for this dataset
source, target, source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh = prepare_dataset(
    voxel_size)

result_ransac = execute_global_registration(source_down, target_down,
                                            source_fpfh, target_fpfh,
                                            voxel_size)

print(result_ransac.transformation)
draw_registration_result(source_down, target_down, result_ransac.transformation)

result_icp = refine_registration(source, target, source_fpfh, target_fpfh,
                                 voxel_size)

print(result_icp)
draw_registration_result(source, target, result_icp.transformation)
```

The output result is a total of 3 steps.

1. Before global registration
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2jjV.png)
2. after global registration
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkm97.png)
3. after local registration
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUUL6.png)

Can you tell me in detail why the demo data works but mine doesn't? pls*10000000

l'm trying

1. Setting parameters to various values
2. Register to a simpler form of cylinder data